# Is there a WebDAV log for SharePoint 2013 Farm?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, webdav

Our developers are experiencing intermittent timeouts when transferring files to a SharePoint 2013 Farm. Is there a WebDAV log?

Comment: Hello @tjreeddoc welcome to SharePoint SE , please don't forget to **Mark**  the correct and useful answer as accepted in case it helped and solved your issue, Thank you for your contribution. For more details check https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 4):

There's no specific WebDAV logs, however:

1. WebDAV is nothing else than specific HTTP requests: WebDAV requests do appear in the standard IIS logs.
2. WebDAV requests are processed by SharePoint: any application error should appear in the SharePoint ULS logs.

If you need to watch more deeply what happens at the protocol level, you'd need to inspect the network traces with a tool like HTTP Fiddler (client side) or WireShark (client/server side).